# How to add AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111 to ProgramTest

Tags: solana-program-test

I am getting this error :

```
[2024-01-07T15:07:17.830011345Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]

[2024-01-07T15:07:17.830133982Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Unknown program AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111
```

While i am loading solana_address_lookup_table_program in my ProgramTest :

```
    program.add_builtin_program(
        "solana-address-lookup-table-program",
        solana_address_lookup_table_program::id(),
        solana_address_lookup_table_program::processor::process_instruction,
    );
```

Any idea how to load it correctly ?

Comment: are you testing the program locally on localnet or devnet ?

Comment: Are you using an old version of the solana-program-test crate? Old versions might not have the address lookup table program.